# Equivalence of criteria using logarithmic transformation

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

Is the following criterion:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x} $$

Equivalent to:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial y\partial x} $$

Because $\ln$ function is a bijection?

Comment: Your criterion assesses closedness of $df$, not exactness. It is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand what "assessing exactness of $df$" means here. The form $df$ is exact because it is $df$; there is nothing else to say about this.

Comment: I have edited the question.